# Why is AChE inhibited by triflates not susceptible to reactivation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, proteins, enzymes

According to a [report](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA129649.pdf), certain esters of trifluoromethanesulfonic acid are capable of acting as irreversible inhibitors of acetylcholinesterase. Also, 3-PAM, while capable of reactivating AChE inhibited by methanesulfonates, will not reactivate AChE inhibited by a triflate. Why is this the case? Does the size of the fluorine atoms sterically hinder the approach of the reactivator? Is the adduct simply unreactive? Does it age, and if so, what is the aging mechanism?